# Diffie Hellman (work out b)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

This is the question in full. Suppose that p − 1 = 2rs, where r and s are primes, both fairly close to p p/2 (but r doesn't equal s). Somehow Eve has found out the value of b mod r and mod s. Can she find out what b is? If so, how?

Comment: What is $b$?  Bob's exponent or his primitive power?

Comment: In a previous question $b$ was bob's private key, the question just before this asked about the discrete log problem so i'm not sure now.

Comment: This is the follow up question if it helps. In fact it is Alice who is trying to discover Bob’s key. Bob has unwisely agreed that Alice may choose both p and m, and has also agreed to set up two shared secrets using the same system. Alice cannot solve the discrete log problem in a group of size close to p, but she has sufficient computing power to be able to solve the discrete log problem in any cyclic group of order close to root(p/2). Bearing in mind part (d), explain how Alice can find Bob’s key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Eve can find $b$.  Let's make sure we're on the same page, though, by clearly declaring the problem.

Alice and Bob have publicly declared the prime $p$ and a primitive element (generator) $g$ for the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$.  Alice chooses an integer power $a$ in secret, and Bob does the same choosing $b$.  Alice computes $A= g^a \mod p$ and Bob computes $B= g^b \mod p$, and they both exchange the results of their computations (but not $a$ or $b$).  Eve the eavesdropper sees all of their transmissions.

The point is that--by Euler's Theorem--**their choices of exponents only matter** mod $\varphi(p)$.  But $\varphi(p)=p-1$, and your problem tells you something very strong about this.  Eve knows $b \mod r$ and $b \mod s$, and $r$ and $s$ are distinct primes, so Eve can use any simple implementation of the Chinese Remainder Theorem and recover $b \mod 2rs$.  Since this is also $b \mod p-1$, Eve has recovered $b$ and hence the secret key.

In this attack, she may not recover Bob's $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, but by my remarks above it doesn't matter.  Getting $b$ right up to multiples of $p-1$ is good enough.

Comment: Thank you, how would Alice find bob's key in the second part and what is the significance of her choosing both p and m in this case?

Comment: What is $m$?

You should see why discovering Bob's $b$ is a huge problem for Alice and Bob.  The calculation of their key is $K = B^a$ or $K = A^b$.  Since $A$ is publicly transmitted and $b$ is now uncovered, Eve just calculates $A^b$ and she's done.  By symmetry, it also suffices to uncover $a$ and use the public $B$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're asking about your second question, not the one posted in your OP.  I don't know:  I haven't thought about it.  I still don't know what $m$ is.

Comment: I think it refers back to m being the public key which they use for diffie-hellman but as p and m are public in the diffie hellman process i don't see why Alice picking them would be a huge problem for Bob

Comment: I guarantee the key is not public in DHKE.  Do you mean $m$ is the base of their exponentials?

Comment: "Note that only a, b, and (g^{ab} mod p = g^{ba} mod p) are kept secret. All the other values – p, g, ga mod p, and gb mod p – are sent in the clear." In this case g is used instead of m [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#General_overview)

Comment: SInce Alice is allowed to choose $p$, she presumably can choose it so that she can discern $p-1=2rs$ as before.   Alice can solve DLP in modulus $r$ or $s$.

From here, I don't now.  When Alice receives $B= g^b \mod p$ from Bob, she can reduce all this mod $r$ and solve that DLP.  That won't give $b$, but something correct mod $r-1$ (again, because we're in the exponent).  I would ponder:  if $x \equiv y \mod r-1$ and $x$ and $y$ are represented as integers below $r-1$, do we still have $x \equiv y \mod r$.  Does this help you reduce to the previous problem?

Comment: yes it does now thanks